# Wait for Updates to Text File Before Reading - Javascript/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I've created a Discord trivia bot using Node JS, and I'm having trouble getting it to read a text file correctly.

I would like to have it read the file AFTER it has been updated with the points, but it always reads as blank (due to the async/sync nature of JS, I assume).

Here is the code for declaring the trivia game winner:

```
    finalScores = readFullText('triviaresults.txt')
    receivedMessage.channel.send("The winner is " + triviaWinner + " with 5 points. Congratulations!")
                                                 //"Final scores: \n" + finalScores)
```

Here is the code for reading the triviaresults.txt file:

```
    function readFullText(filename){
         var data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')
         return data
    }
```

Here is the code for updating the triviaresults.txt file with points:

```
function writeToResults(user){
const fs = require('fs')
var foundName = "false"
var newText = ""

try {
    //read the file into lines variable, split at new lines
    var lines = require('fs').readFileSync('triviaresults.txt', 'utf-8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter(Boolean);

    //loop through each line, checking if the user was found
    lines.forEach((line) => {
        if (user == line.split(':')[0]) {
            //gets users current score
            var oldScore = line.split(': ')[1]
            //converts current score to integer for adding purposes
            oldScore = parseInt(oldScore, 10)
            //adds 1 to their score
            var newScore = oldScore + 1
            //replaces old line with new line/score
            var newLine = line.replace(/.$/,newScore)
            //sets foundName to true so it knows not to add the name at the bottom
            foundName = "true"
            newText = newText + newLine + "\n"
            scoreCheck = newScore
        } else {
            if (newText == "") {
                newText = line + "\n"
            } else {
                newText = newText + line + "\n"
            }
        }
    })

    if (foundName == "false") {
        if (newText == "") {
            newText = user + ": 1"
        } else {
            newText = newText + user + ": 1"
        }
    }

    fs.writeFile('triviaresults.txt', newText, (err) => { 
        if (err) throw err; 
    }) 
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Error:', e.stack);
}}
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution and I'm not able to see to it due to my limited experience with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use callback function which you call after you write the file. **And** you don't even need to read the file afterwards since you already have the content as a `newText` so just return it.

```
function writeToResults(user, callback){ // <------ callback

   ...

   fs.writeFile('triviaresults.txt', newText, (err) => { 
       if (err) throw err; 
       callback(newText); // <------- callback
   }) 
};
```

Then write the file and you get the data back:

```
writeToResults(user, function(finalScores){
    // no need for finalScores = readFullText('triviaresults.txt')
    // the function returned the data already
    finalScores;

    // if you didn't use callback(newText); then you would need to read the file here
    fs.readFile('triviaresults.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data){

    });
});
```

> **Note: Don't use synchronous versions of readFile/writeFile unless you need to. It's blocking the whole application until the file is read into memory/written to disk.**